# What is an “apiEndpoint” in poc-ipfs config file

Tags: javascript, development

In the poc-ipfs app blueprint from IOTA’s GitHub, they have a config file on the client side (link below), one of the parts of the script contains “apiEndpoint”, I do not know what would go there for a url, or how to use it. Does anyone know?

The GitHub link:

https://github.com/iotaledger/poc-ipfs/blob/master/client/DEPLOYMENT.md

Comment: As I understand the documentation (no experience with that package though) is that you first need to deploy the api subproject, before you can deploy the client subproject. Point the apiEndpoint of the client subproject to the URL where you deployed the api subproject.

Comment: @mihi So would something like http://localhost:8080/ work? What would be another example of a URL that an API would use?

Comment: When you are running the api endpoint on the same machine as the client, `http://localhost:8080/` could work, yes.